# Raw data from /dev/graphics/fb0

Tags: android, framebuffer

Is there any way to get raw data from framebuffer /dev/graphics/fb0 programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the right permission, yes, you can read it as any other file.
Framebuffer devices are usually `root:graphics` with `rw` permission for both user and group.

But if you are asking about a normal application without root permission the answer is no.